# Metric spaces and the induced metric

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

I'm having trouble with the following problem:

Suppose $A \subset M$ is a subset of a metric space $(M,d)$. Prove that $U \subset A$ is an open set in the metric space $(A, d_{\vert A \times A})$ if and only if there is an open set $W \subset M$ s.t. $U = W \cap A$.

I don't really know where to start on this. I'm not looking for the solution, just a hint.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

A set $U$ is open in a metric space if and only if given any point $x \in U$, you can find some $\epsilon$-ball containing $x$ that is contained in $U$. Considering also that $A$ has the same metric as $M$, can you think of a way to use this property to prove what you're looking for?